# New asset path issue with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I'm trying to add a new asset path to the pipeline...
I've created a directory "fonts" inside /app/assets/
and wrote this line:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

inside my application.rb config file.
But I get a 404 error browsing this: localhost:3000/assets/fonts/

Please help me.

Comment: I found the solution by changing image-url to font-url inside stylesheets... now the application provides my fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Use just `localhost:3000/fonts`.